# Excel: Combine Multiple Rows and Adding Similar Columns

Tags: excel

Hopefully this is an easy question: I need to combine some similar rows in a spreadsheet but I need to add the values in one of the columns. For example, the data looks like this:

```
Result  Count  ID
100     75     xxx
100     10     xxx
100      5     xxx
95      35     yyy
95      40     yyy
95      10     yyy
```

I would like to combine all rows so that there is just one row for ID xxx and one row for yyy so that the final spreadsheet would look like:

```
Result     Count     ID
100        114       xxx
95         75        yyy
```

I know that I could probably use sum but I'm dealing with several thousand rows of data and was wondering if there is a way to do this more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Your example does not make sense, the numbers don't add up. Can you also have something like:

```
Result     Count     ID
100        114       xxx
95         75        xxx
80         70        yyy
```

I guess you could get very far with pivot tables. There are many other ways but pivot tables are more visual and easily customisable.

Select your data, go to the Data menu and click on Pivot table. The pivot table builder will pop up. Drag the ID column into the Row Labels list, drag the Count into the Values list and Result into the Row labels list again.

You can actually slice and dice your dataset any way you want with the pivot tables. To learn more just pop-up the help(F1) for pivot tables and follow some examples.